# Что такое предикатная функция?

Tags: c++, функции, c++11, логика, предикат

Изучаю С++. В литературе одну из функций назвали предикатной. Что это может значить, или это такой перевод ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим такую задачу. У нас есть, скажем, вектор целых чисел, и мы хотим вывести на экран только положительные числа.

Как мы это сделаем?

```
void out(const vector<int>& v)
{
    for(auto i: v) 
        if (i > 0) cout << i << " ";
}
```

А если вывести все, больше 5?

```
void out(const vector<int>& v)
{
    for(auto i: v) 
        if (i > 5) cout << i << " ";
}
```

Похоже? Да. Так и тянет объединить их в

```
void out(const vector<int>& v, int value)
{
    for(auto i: v) 
        if (i > value) cout << i << " ";
}
```

Но что, если мы захотим вывести только четные? Только те, для которых синус положителен?

Все это можно обобщить, например, так:

```
void out(const vector<int>& v, bool(*)(int) pred)
{
    for(auto i: v) 
        if (pred(i)) cout << i << " ";
}
```

Где `pred` - функция, которая проверяет некоторое условие, [предикат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82). И будут выведены только те числа, для которых функция `pred` вернет значение `true`. А как мы ее напишем - наше дело. Например,

```
bool pred(int i) { return i > 5; }
```

Вот, по сути, и все. Остальное - функция, или лямбда, шаблон или нет, от скольки аргументов и т.д. и т.п. - не суть важно. Предикативная функция - проверяющая некоторое условие, ***предикат***, для своего(их) аргумента(ов).

Ну и - предикаты весьма широко применяются в алгоритмах стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это функция, которая может возвращать только логические true/false?

Comment: @DidMazay Ну почему, она может возвращать и `int`, например :) Важнее, не какова ее сигнатура, а в каком качестве она применяется, для чего.

Comment: Предикат всегда возвращает bool, это понятие из логики, а не C++. Предикат это обобщённое утверждение, где есть переменные. Утверждение может быть либо истинным, либо ложным и ничем другим.

Comment: @ixSci Когда речь идет о функции (а речь шла о ней - *это функция, которая может возвращать только логические true/false*), то вполне годится возврат чего-то, что неявно преобразуется в булев результат.

Comment: @Harry, предикат не может возвращать ничего кроме `bool`, преобразование тут роли не играет. Если она возвращает не `bool`, тогда это не предикат.

Comment: @ixSci Это уже схоластика. `copy_if(begin(v),end(v),begin(w),[](int x){ return (x%2) ? 0 : 5; });` Работает? работает. Не `bool`? не `bool`. Тогда что же это? Важен не тип в языке программирования, а семантическое содержание.

Comment: @Harry, серьёзно? Правильно использование терминов это схоластика? Ну тогда ладно.

Comment: @ixSci Хорошо, как говорится, тогда по гамбургскому счету :) Покажите, где это в стандарте. Там я нашел как раз - **The `Predicate` parameter ... returns a value testable as true. In other words ... it should work
correctly in the construct pred(*first) _contextually converted_ to bool.**

Comment: @Harry вот, нашел: *"... выступает в роли пропозиционной функции (т.е. функции, областью значений которой служат высказывания) ... Мы будем называть предикатом всякую пропозиционную функцию с любым числом независимых переменных"* - Клини С.К. Математическая логика. — М.:Мир, 1973.

Comment: Человек задал вполне конкретный вопрос: «что такое предикатная функция или может с переводом проблема?» Так вот, предикат остаётся предикатом хоть в C++, хоть на хинди — стандарт C++ тут абсолютно иррелевантен. Я ещё раз повторяю, это понятие из логики и оно никакой трактовке не подлежит.

Comment: @ixSci Не возражаю. Только логика ничего не знает о типе `bool`, как и о любом другом типе C/C++. Или вы говорите о логике, и тогда не говорите о том, что предикат должен возвращать тип `bool` (как и, соответственно, не говорите о том, что ответили на вопрос, в котором речь четко идет о C++ - см. начало вопроса), а просто об истинности или ложности предиката - каковая не имеет отношения к конкретному типу. Или вы говорите о C++, и тогда опять же не следует замыкаться на функциях (точнее, функциональных объектах), возвращающих тип `bool`, потому что стандарт говорит только о приведении к нему.

Comment: `bool` пришёл из логики, так что Ваше заявление не верно. Впрочем, я уже несколько раз объяснил свою позицию, добавить мне больше нечего.

Comment: @ixSci Я тоже :) Уберите тип `bool`, скажите, что предикат возвращает логическое значение - и я с вами не спорю. На сем и закончим дискуссию. Только вот... Предикаты в C/C++ появились тогда, когда типа `bool` там и близко не было - это были, по-вашему, не предикаты? :)

Comment: Всё, что я хотел сказать, я уже сказал — предикат может быть либо истинным, либо ложным. Всё остальное не имеет никакого отношения к этому понятию. Ни реализация C++, ни что либо другое.

Comment: @ixSci  *@Harry, предикат не может возвращать ничего кроме `bool`, преобразование тут роли не играет. Если она возвращает не `bool`, тогда это не предикат.* (c) ixSci QED На сем к этой теме белее не возвращаюсь.

Comment: 1. Мы говорим тут о логике. Двоичной? Троичной? ...? Классический образец предиката во всех стандартных библиотеках (почти) всех современных языков - `Array.sort(myArray, pred)`, где `pred` принимает два элемента массива и __возвращает `-1`/`0`/`1`__. Это логика троичная/тринарная и это предикат.

Comment: почему вы пишите `for(auto i: v)` а не `for(int i: v)`? как правильней?

Comment: @Danis Это, в общем-то, совершенно все равно. Как правильно посчитать - 3*2 или 2*3? :)

Answer (score 14):

> **Предикатом** называется функция, возвращающая тип `bool` (или другое
>   значение, которое может быть автоматически преобразовано к `bool`).
>   Предикаты широко используются в *STL*. В частности, функции сравнения в
>   стандартных ассоциативных контейнерах представляют собой предикаты.
>   Предикатные функции часто передаются в виде параметров таким
>   алгоритмам, как `find_if`, и различным алгоритмам сортировки.

[Источник](http://cpp.com.ru/meyers/ch6.html).

Answer (score 2):

Вот написал небольшой пример.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, typename Cmp>
T* array_move(T* fa, T* la, Cmp cmp){
   T* p;
   while((fa != la) && cmp(*fa))
      ++fa;

   for(p = fa; fa != la; ++fa){
      if(cmp(*fa)){
         std::swap(*fa, *p);
         ++p;
      }
   }
   return p;
}

int main(void){
   std::ostream_iterator<int> _out(std::cout, " ");
   int  a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
   int  n   = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

   //переставить в начало массива чётные числа
   auto e1  = array_move(a, a + n, [] (int x) { 
       return ((x & 1) == 0);
   });
   std::copy(a, e1, _out);
   std::cout << std::endl;

   //переставить в начало массива только те числа которые кратны трём
   auto e2 = array_move(a, a + n, [] (int x){
      return ((x % 3) == 0);
   });
   std::copy(a, e2, _out);
   std::cout << std::endl;

   //переставить в начало массива только те числа у которых включен 3-ий бит
   auto e3 = array_move(a, a + n, [] (int x){
      return (((x >> 2) & 1) == 1);
   });
   std::copy(a, e3, _out);
   return 0;
}
```

И какой можно сделать вывод о предикате неважно как он выполнен структурой, функцией или лямдой? И так, предикат это условие которые встраивается из вне, тем самым позволяя функции быть более функциональной по сравнению с функциями без предикатов. Даже малейшего взгляда на код достаточно увидеть преимущество использования предиката, ибо без него пришлось писать мне три разные функции для выполнения задания, а если заданий будет 40? К примеру переместить в начало массива:

1. простые числа
2. числа Фибоначчи
3. нечётные числа
4. отрицательные числа
5. положительные числа
6. числа которые больше 100 но меньше 500
7. числа у которых включено 5-бит

...